# How to include a C++ project in my own in Android

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface

as per the title i want to include a C++ project in my own project in Android Studio.

I tried copying all the files in my */cpp* folder and manually including them into my MakeList.txt, but i got numerous compilation errors, because some system library is missing (such as  files).

The project i would to include is [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero).
Is there a method to include it in my app?

Comment: Do you know about NDK ?

Comment: Yes, i do. But i got some error because apparently there is some library that is not found

Comment: Without stating the specific errors, this is unanswerable.  In general, the NDK is a limited build target - you can't expect everything to be supported.  Chances are someone has already ported that project, so your best recourse may be a web search (using Stackoverflow to ask where you can find code is prohibited).

Comment: Thank you, i've already searched, but i didn't find anything. The problem is that the project is trying to include a file from "boost" folder, but it is not found anywhere. I would try to download boost library and add to my project "/cpp", but it is impossible due to its size (more than 1GB)

Comment: How is downloading 1GB impossible? Or are you saying that it's causing problems with the IDE if you place the Boost sources in your project directory? If so, have you tried placing it elsewhere on your harddrive and then specifying in your makefile(s) where to look for the Boost headers?

Comment: Really, I was worried about the apk size